# Can we interpret $e^x$ as an unique fixpoint of the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$ and what would it mean?

Tags: calculus, differential-operators

I'm not sure if there is some similar question, but I didn't find something on this topic as I wanted, so please spare me in case I overlooked something.

Back in school I've learned that if you try to find a function that solves $\frac{d}{dx}a^x = a^x$ and try different values for a that you will get closer to 2.71..., which is later on defined as $e$ the Euler's number.

Now I've also learned that *we can reinterpret the derivative of a function as a linear transformation whose graph is (after an appropriate translation) the best linear approximation to the graph of the original function, with the Jacobian matrix as this linear transformation* - as of Wikipedia, but I'm sure we also thought about it like that in my real analysis class back then.

Back to my initial question in this context this would kind of mean that $e^x$ is an unique fixpoint of the "map" (I'm not sure if this terminology is correct for the derivative, I think it's an operator) $\frac{d}{dx}$. Even more it would mean that the best linear approximation of $e^x$ is the function itself.

When it comes to operators my knowledge is bit rudimentary, so I don't know if there is a necessary condition for an operator to have a fixpoint. I only know some fixpoint theorems, so I would welcome some suggestions on this.

So in general I have my troubles understanding what this interpretation means for $e^x$and $e$ itself. Does this mean we cannot approximate $e^x$ with a linear approximation - could we do it nonlinear then and how? Also why is it $e$ - is it like $\pi$ just a coincidence for a constant? How can we view the derivative in this context - maybe also geometric or algebraic?

Thank you if you read until here, I hope you can help me understanding this a bit better.

Comment: For starters: If $c$ is real, the function$f(x) = ce^{x}$ is a fixed point of the derivative operator, so there's no uniqueness. On the real line (or on the complex plane), however, these function are the only solutions of $f' = f$. In the real setting, $f(x) = ce^{x}$ has the property that at each point $x$, the _slope of the tangent line at $x$_ is equal to _the height of the graph at $x$_.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks, you're absolutely right, I missed the scaling part with a real factor, so let's say we understand "unique" as unique up to a real factor.

Comment: You can have a linear approximation of a nonlinear function. In fact, it's the nonlinearity of the function that makes this an _approximation._ If the function were linear then you could have a linear formula that matched the function _exactly._

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for correcting me, my chain of thoughts was a bit messed up there. I'll edit it right away.

Answer (score 2):

In order to speak about a “fixed point” of a linear map, we need a map from some vector space $V$ to itself.

For this case, the space can be $V=C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, the functions having derivatives of any order on the real line.

The map $D\colon V\to V$ that associates to each function its derivative is linear. A fixed point is thus a function $f$ which is equal to its derivative:
$$
f(x)=f'(x) \qquad\text{for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$}
$$
There are several ways for finding the solutions. A simple one is to assume $f$ is a solution and to consider
$$
h(x)=e^{-x}f(x)
$$
Then $h'(x)=-e^{-x}f(x)+e^{-x}f'(x)=-e^{-x}+e^{-x}f(x)=0$. Therefore $h$ is constant, having zero derivative over $\mathbb{R}$. So, for every $x$,
$$
c=e^{-x}f(x)
$$
where $c=h(0)$, and therefore
$$
f(x)=ce^x
$$
Conversely, any such function satisfies the requirement, so we have found all solutions to the fixed point problem to be of the form
$$
c\exp
$$
where $\exp$ is the standard exponential function defined by $\exp(x)=e^x$ and $c$ is any scalar (real number).

We can notice that the set of fixed points forms a *line* in $V$, that is, a subspace of dimension one.

In other terminology, $1$ is an *eigenvalue* of $D$, with dimension one eigenspace.

Comment: Thanks, that's a really useful comment. As far as I comprehend it that means $1$ is an eigenvalue of $D$ as you noted and the corresponding eigenvector would be any element of the form $c \exp$, isn't it?

Comment: @ApostleoftheHelix Yes, for $c\ne0$. Similarly, the function $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. One thing still makes me think: I get that $D$ has every element of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ as an eigenvalue. What does this mean for the trace of $D$ in this context - maybe also it's determinant?

Comment: Oh I think the trace wouldn't be useful here since if we look onto the derivative we need to make sure that it's a bounded operator if we want to get it's eigenvalues since the space is infinite dimensional. So let's think in another direction: could we construct a basis with our previous thoughts. I know this is not easy, because of the infinite dimensions, but would it be in relation to $e^x$ ?

Comment: @ApostleoftheHelix Also $0$ is an eigenvalue. The problem you pose is very important, actually. One can define an inner product, but since the spectrum is unbounded, the derivation operator in unbounded as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_{1}(1)$ denotes the set of all one variable functions which their first derivative exists. Now the operation $\frac{d}{dx}:C_1(1)\rightarrow C_0(1)$ can be defined easily by the set of relations for derivation, where $C_0(1)$ is the set of all one variable functions. From that we can understand that this operation is linear as you mentioned. To understand your question it is convenient to see your new space (set of all one variable functions that has first derivative). Now the fixed point of $\frac{d}{dx}$ in this space has meaning and is $e^x(=\exp(x))$. You only need to re-think on the space where you are working on.

Comment: The range of the $\frac{d}{dx}$ operator is not contained in $C_1(1)$, because a differentiable function is not necessarily twice differentiable.

Comment: Try $C^\infty$ instead of $C^1$.

Comment: You are right my bad. Range should be set of all one variable functions.